# Can't setMetadata while downloading files via fileTransfer.download in iOS in Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, callback, download, icloud

I'm downloading lots of files in the loop and want to setMetadata for each downloaded file (to not backup in iCloud). I'm using simple code with two console.logs. The problem is that files are downloading but no console.log message is displayed. Neither error or success, nothing. Please help.

Code:

```
var onSetMetadataWin = function() {
    console.log("success setting metadata") 
} 
var onSetMetadataFail = function() { 
    console.log("error setting metadata") 
} 

fileTransfer.download( 
    uri, 
    filePath, 
    function(entry) { 
        entry.setMetadata(onSetMetadataWin, onSetMetadataFail, {"com.apple.MobileBackup": 1});
    }, 
    function(error) {}, 
    false 
);
```

Comment: [superabuh](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3574185) posted this comment as an answer (I flagged the answer for deletion, but it's a useful comment): Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to comment. But I'm having the same problem as the OP. It seems like the bug is new to version 0.4.3 of the file transfer plugin. I've created a bug report at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6525

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in cordova-file plugin that has now been fixed in the v1.1.1dev.

If you are busting to try it out you could remove your file-transfer and file plugin and install the development (just remember to add release one back in when it's out).

```
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.file
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file.git 
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
```

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6525